# Question time period limit

Tags: discussion, support, bug, reputation

I sometimes have more than 6 problems in a 24-hour period, or more than 50 in a 30-day period, so I think that it would be really good if the limit could be raised, or if you could add to your limit by taking of a question from the next day.

Or a better system, as I imagine that this is mostly to stop spam and encourage new users to do research before asking, would be if users with, say, 2k rep, or something like that could have the limit removed, or for the limit to go up at least.

Or even for a mod to have to confirm that the question is good, before it is posted to the site (this would probably be for higher rep users though, lower ones just wouldn't be able to post).

Comment: @guntbert: Ok, I have done that.

Comment: The better system is to [RTFM](http://gaarde.org/acronyms/?lookup=RTFM)!  **;-)**

Comment: Why the down-votes?  I never ran into this limit, but it's a legit question as I had no clue all these limits existed and now other people will too!µ

Comment: @Fabby downvotes often express disagreement on meta, especially on feature requests.

Comment: @Fabby I downvoted it (along with someone else), because I don't agree with increasing the limit of askable questions per month. The question (is more of a statement tough) is legit, well written and brings up useful numbers, nothing against that - I simply disagree with the proposal.

Comment: **kos, muru**: Thanks for the feedback...

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your past questions, I strongly disagree. Your research level is terrible to non-existent. Quite a few are plain RTFM problems. You very well may have 50 questions in a 30 day period, but you certainly don't have 50 decent, worthwhile questions in a 30 day period. If you have trouble understanding why, [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit).

Comment: One fool can ask more questions than ten wise men can answer...  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby That's extremely true

Comment: However, @ParanoidPanda, nothing against you here (obviously). But I have to agree with muru's statement. 50 questions a month is *plenty*. The only times I've asked it was because: 1. I was a noob 2. I didn't understand well the topic i was asking about 3. I had a legit doubt. So, speaking for myself, just 1 out of 3 questions of mine were really worth asking (on average, but that's actually pretty accurate). RTFM *thoroughly* is the best thing one should do, seriously.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda knows I'm not trying to depress him but to make him laugh.  He should do some more reading IMHO, but he knows that...